# The equality of sets in measure theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

When I read the Stein's book: Real Analysis, I found a equality of sets which I do not understand.

Suppose $a\in \mathbb{R}$,  then

$\{x:f(x)+g(x) > a\} = \bigcup_{r\in \mathbb{Q}} \big(\{x:f(x)>a-r\}\cap \{x:g(x)>r\} \big)$,

where $\mathbb{Q}$ denotes the rational.

In my view, the $r\in \mathbb{Q}$ should change to $r\in \mathbb{R}$. Why is this still true for $\mathbb{Q}$? If this is true,  how can I derive the equality from $r \in \mathbb{R}$ to $r \in \mathbb{Q}$? Many thanks!

Comment: Your view is wrong. It's still true for $\mathbb{Q}$ because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ (which implies $y > a$ iff there is some rational $r > a$ with $y > r$)

Comment: Yes, the rationals are dense in real. But how can I derive equality from $r \in \mathbb{R}$ to $r \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Call $F_r = \{x \in X| f(x) > a-r \}$, $G_r = \{x \in X| g(x) > r\}$, $U_1 = \bigcup_{r \in \mathbb{Q}} F_r \cap G_r$, $U_2 = \bigcup_{r \in \mathbb{R}} F_r \cap G_r$, $A = \{x \in X| f(x)+g(x)>a\}$. Then we have to prove

$$U_1 = U_2 = A$$

Let's start with $U_1 = U_2$:

- "$\subseteq$": obvious because we have a bigger union
- "$\supseteq$": fix $x \in U_2$, so $\exists r \in \mathbb{R}$ $f(x)>a-r, g(x)>r$. Because the functions $\phi(r) = f(x) - a +r$ and $\psi(r)= g(x)+a$ are continuous in $r$, we have that $\Phi = \{r \in \mathbb{R}|\phi(r)>0\}$ and $\Psi = \{r \in \mathbb{R}|\psi(r)>0\}$ are open. Because $\Psi \cap \Phi$ is also open and is not empty (because $x \in U_2$  is the element that defines the functions $\psi, \phi$) then $\Psi \cap \Phi \cap \mathbb{Q} \neq \emptyset$ because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Now to prove $U_2 = A$:

- "$\subseteq$": obvious
- "$\supseteq$": fix $x \in A$, so $f(x)+g(x)>a$. Call $r = g(x)- \varepsilon$ ($\varepsilon>0$), so $g(x)>r$. Can we find $\varepsilon$ s.t. also $f(x) >a-r$? Yes: $f(x) >a-r \iff f(x)+g(x)>a+\epsilon$ and because the set $\{t \in \mathbb{R}|f(x)+g(x)>a+t\}$ is open...

Comment: Many thanks! It is a strict and beautiful derivation.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to see that every real number $a\in\mathbb R$ can be defined as the limit of a Cauchy sequence of rational numbers $\langle q_n\rangle_{n\in\mathbb N}$ strictly less than $a$. For every $n\in\mathbb N$, choose a rational number $q_n\in(a-2^{-n},a)$. This is possible, because it is an open interval and $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

We then have that $x\geq a$ if and only if $x>q_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

The counterintuitive part seems to be that the limit of a Cauchy sequence of rational numbers is not a rational number. But this is perfectly possible, consider for example Euler's famous series:
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}
$$

The fact that not every Cauchy sequence of rational numbers has a rational number as limit, means that the space of rational numbers is not *complete*. If we take the set of rational numbers, and close it under limits of Cauchy sequences (i.e. we add a new number for any Cauchy sequence that does not converge to a rational number), then we get exactly all the real numbers. This is called the *completion* of the rational numbers, and is a common way to construct $\mathbb R$ from $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Good explanation, thanks. I agree with your conclusion "We then have that $x\geq a$ if and only if $x>q_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$".

Comment: The best way of course is to prove it: if $x\leq q_n$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$, then show that $x<a$.